# Every couple emails marked by gmail as "Couldn't verify Sender"

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix

I'm using postfix as a send only solution from a debian server.  The sever is a subdomain, I have and SPF record set for the sub domain as follows:

```
"v=spf1 a -all"
```

Obviously there is an A record pointing the subdomain to the correct IP.  The emails come from username@subdomain.example.com.

What am I missing here?  The hostname of the server is not the same as the subdomain, but I can't imagine it matters when I set postfix to use subdomain.example.com.

It seems like every other email gets flagged as not being able to verify.

EDIT:

I should also note that the primary domain is also used for email and has it's own SPF records.  It uses G-Suite(G-apps).

Comment: try running dnstracer on your domain, could be you have a misbehaivng DNS server.

Comment: "every other" problems are usually related to network issues like double default gateways, or double route entries, or double DNS records ... each having one good/working setting the other being bad/invalid setting. You may need to trace the validation steps and execute them manually several times and maybe you will spot the issue. (ex. ping the domain to validate, solve the name of the mail domain, retrieve any relevant DNS record).

Comment: Good Call!  My A record is ip4 and the messages that are failing are sourcing ip6.

Comment: Gmail/G Suite has a variety of long standing bugs in its implementation of SPF verification, which cause false positives such as this (and much more rarely, false negatives). You've almost certainly run into multiple of these bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem.  IPv6 was enabled on the outgoing interface and the failed messages were sourcing from the ip6 address.  Disabled ip6 and everything works.

Comment: Hi, can you accept your own answer please?